# SQL (postgresql) update a date column using an interval from data in a join table

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, sql-update, date-arithmetic

In my Postgresql database, I am trying to update a column in one table based on data in that table and another table. In my users table, I'm trying to update the new_date column by adding data in a separate date column to an integer column in months from my plans table (e.g. new_date = 2022-02-27 + 5 months); if this was a single table I could add date + interval '1 month' * months, such as something like - `UPDATE users SET new_date = date + interval '1 month' * months;`  However, I am unable to figure out how to do a similar update using a join table between users and plans, with subqueries or common table expressions.

*users table* (abbreviated): **new_date** to be updated based on **date** + **months**

| date | new_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-21 | null |
| 2022-04-15 | null |

*plans table* (abbreviated)

| months |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 1 |

join table: SELECT users.date, plans.months, users.new_date FROM users JOIN plans ON users.plan_id = plans.id

| date | months | new_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-21 | 5 |  |
| 2022-04-15 | 1 |  |

Result:

updated *users table*:

| date | new_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-21 | 2022-10-21 |
| 2022-04-15 | 2022-05-15 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the tables and multiply the value of the column `months` by `INTERVAL '1 month'` in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE users AS u
SET new_date = u.date + INTERVAL '1 month' * p.months
FROM plans AS p
WHERE p.id = u.plan_id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7e20f245c2f3b6005afc93b6232b3b77).

Comment: Great, thanks: final code without the "pseudo" structure of the tables: ```UPDATE users AS u
SET subscription_active_until = u.confirmed_at + INTERVAL '1 month' * p.months + INTERVAL '3 days'
FROM plans AS p
WHERE p.id = u.plan_id;```